# WPF: Make ListBox full height of parent, but also be scrollable

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I have a simple app that has three columns in the window. In the middle column, I have a ListBox component.

What I want is the ListBox to stretch the full height of the column, but also be scrollable when it has a lot of stuff in it. Right now, it's not scrollable. I can fix this by adding a `Height` (e.g. `Height="300"`) property to it, but then it won't stretch with the column anymore. What do I do?

```
<Window x:Class="UI.MainWindow"
    <!-- window stuff -->
<Border Padding="10">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" MinWidth="150" MaxWidth="200" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <!-- column 1 stuff -->

            <StackPanel x:Name="LogLines" Grid.Column="1">
                <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                    <Label>Search</Label>
                    <TextBox x:Name="Searchbox" Height="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="TextBox" Width="120" />
                    <CheckBox x:Name="ErrorsOnlyCheckbox" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
                        Errors only
                    </CheckBox>
                </StackPanel>

                <ListBox
                    x:Name="LogLinesList"
                    ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="True" />
            </StackPanel>

            <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Width="10" />

            <!-- column 3 stuff -->
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Border>
</Window>
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Container of your `ListBox` is `StackPanel`. `StackPanel` will increase regarding child controls. You should use another container, try to use `Grid` instead

```
<Grid x:Name="LogLines" Grid.Column="1">
     <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Width="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Width="*" />
     </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    
     <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Row="0">
          ....
     </StackPanel>
    
     <ListBox Grid.Row="1"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: I implemented this, but ended up still having the issue. However, I then noticed my entire window was wrapped in a StackPanel. I removed that unneeded StackPanel and the issue has been fixed.

Comment: Oh, I did not pay attention to second StackPanel. Anyway I glad you resolved issue.